# Deduct milliseconds from DateTime in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a dateTime in this format: 2015-04-29T01:30:27.058Z and time difference of 5000milliseconds. Is there any XSLT function which can deduct this time difference and produce an output of a dateTime?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 2.0 or 1.0? In 2.0 that "timestamp" seems to be an `xs:dateTime` to which you could add a duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 or later (requires an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime) you can use arithmetic with `xs:dateTime` and `xs:dayTimeDuration`, for instance

```
xs:dateTime('2015-04-29T01:30:27.058Z') + xs:dayTimeDuration('-PT0.058S')
```

computes a new `xs:dateTime` `2015-04-29T01:30:27Z`.

The XML schema namespace assumed for the prefix `xs` is `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`.
See http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_dayTimeDuration.html on how `dayTimeDuration`s can be written.

So with that version of the language my suggestion is to make use of those two data types and the arithmetic operations provided instead of going to milliseconds for computations.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0,

```
(xs:dateTime($timeStamp) - xs:dateTime('2000-01-01T00:00:00Z')) 
  div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0.001S')
```

gives the number of milliseconds since the start of the current century.